# Can I define a variable using php outside Ninja Forms and pull it into the form? No QueryString

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, global, ninja

I want to send a form email to any one of about 75 people. This will depend on what page the user came from to get to the form page. I use URL QueryString to set that page value. An easy solution would be to put the email in the QueryString but then it is visable to the Public(User). Ninja Forms allows me to set form field to variable but I can only find the Ninja Form fields and the WP Admin variables to choose from. I can't modify those on the fly. I can pass a value through the QueryString and then use php to do a If Then to define the email. My challenge is, how do I get it into Ninja Forms. If I declared a Global Variable would Ninja Form show that on the choices of fields? Or maybe another Form plugin for WordPress would do this?
Thanks for any suggestions.